# difference between `%in%` and `in` operator in R

Tags: r

What's the difference between the `in` and the `%in%` operator in R? Why do I sometimes need the percentage signs and other times I do not?

Answer (score 8):

The 3 following objects are all functions :

- `identity`
- `%in%`
- `for`

We can call them this way :

```r
`identity`(1)
#> [1] 1
`%in%`(1, 1:2)
#> [1] TRUE
`for`(x, seq(3), print("yes"))
#> [1] "yes"
#> [1] "yes"
#> [1] "yes"
```

But usually we don't!

"identity" is syntactic (i.e. it's a "regular" name, doesn't contain weird symbols etc), AND it is not a protected word so we can skip the tick marks and call just :

```
identity(1)
```

`%in%` is not syntactic but it starts and ends with "%" so it can be used in infix form. you could define your own  `` `%fun%` <-function(x,y) ... `` and use it this way to, so we would call :

```
1 %in% 1:2
```

`for` is a control flow construct, like `if`, `while` and `repeat`, all of those are functions with a given number of arguments, but they come in the language with more convenient ways to call them than the above. here we'd do :

```
for (x in seq(3)) print("yes")
```

`in` is just used to parse the code, it's not a function here (just like `else` isn't either.

`` ?`%in%` ``  will show you what the function does.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you define it, there is no `in` operator in R, only an `%in%` operator. Instead, `in` is “[syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)” as part of the syntax for the `for` loop.

By contrast, [`%in%` is an *actual operator*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) defined in R which tests whether the left-hand expression is contained in the right-hand expression. As other operators in R, `%in%` is a *regular function* and can be called as such:

```
if (`%in%`(x, seq(3, 5))) message("yes")
```

… or it can be redefined:

```
`%in%` = function (x, table) {
    message("I redefined %in%!")
    match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
}

if (5 %in% 1 : 10) message("yes")

# I redefined %in%!
# yes
```

Comment: I feel like *syntactic sugar* is the wrong term for `in`.  I usually think of syntactic sugar as a clearer or more concise way to write things, an alternate to a more annoying alternative. `in` is a necessary part of `for` syntax. You cannot write a `for` loop without it, and there is no alternative, thus `in` is not sugar. I'd actually say `%in%` is more sugar than `in`--binary operators in R could all be thought of as sugar compared to standard functional form `\`%in%\`(a, b)`.

Comment: Though as soon as I post this, I see moody mudskipper's answer and see that `\`for\`(x, seq(3), print("yes"))` works and I am wrong about making `for` loops without `in`. Hmmm. `%in%` still feels sugary to me too. I never knew `in` was sugar.

Comment: Gregor see my answer below for the alternative on how to write a `for` loop ;). IMO syntactic sugar is an acceptable way to describe it, the thing is nobody uses it in its general form

Answer (score 0):

Usage-wise, I have figured out the answer: I can only use `in` when I loop through everything, and `%in%`for checking whether something is contained in something else, e.g.

```
for (x in seq(3)){
 if (x %in% seq(3,5)) print("yes")
}
```